# Closing Questions that could be asked somewhere else

Tags: discussion

As Christianity Q&A were developed, some question that was asked in the main site was question that could have been somewhere else, if it weren't for that that specific site was *not* created. For [example](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/946/what-does-it-mean-to-be-an-heir-of-god-and-a-joint-heir-with-christ).

Now, based on that question, which could have been asked in [Biblical Hermeneutics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1817/biblical-hermeneutics), if it weren't for that site has not been created yet. Can't we do something about this? Like, immediate closure, or something else. Or do we allow it?

Comment: Could you clarify what you are asking here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little difficult to close questions as off-topic in a private beta—when the site's scope isn't fully defined—because it might be on-topic on a site that doesn't currently exist.

Instead, we should be thinking about whether, ignoring any other site or potential site, it's something we want to have here. If it is, it should stay open. If it isn't, it should be closed.

Once that decision's been made, we can think about where it might fit: if it's a really good fit somewhere else, it could be migrated at some point in the future. If it isn't, or the potential site doesn't make it into beta, it can just stay closed as off-topic.

The important thing is to think about this site *first*, other sites *second*.

Given how many other questions about Biblical interpretations have been answered here, this question looks to be on-topic so it shouldn't be closed just because there's a Biblical Hermeneutics proposal.

In general, unless Christianity.SE fails, I think Biblical Hermeneutics is going to have a little bit of trouble carving out a specific site scope.

Comment: +1 for **migrate in the future**. I've asked I think two questions that make a good fit (IMO) here, and a better one on Biblical Hermeneutics. Since they're on-topic and there's currently no other site, why not.